# Why do I get this python syntax error

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this syntax error while writing Python code for Django.

```
File "/home/acne/acne/acne/settings.py", line 57
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)],
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[image: error]

How can I solve this? But more important, how can I avoid this kind of error?

Comment: ... is added by sublime you need pass the values like 'DIRS':[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, YOUr_DIR)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly where the python interpreter is saying. You want to replace ... with a string with the name of your templates folder.

Update:

For example if your templates folder is called "templates":

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#templates

The error appears because ... doesn't mean anything in Python. If you want to avoid this kind of errors you can take a look at a book on Python, like An Introduction to Python by van Rossum.

If you are starting in Django, the first tutorial is a must do: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/ The Django documentation is excelent.